# Not able to set parameters in http/2 transport

Tags: go, httpclient, http2

I want to have a Go HTTP/2 client for contacting a HTTP/2 supported server using h2c. For which I used Go's http2 transport, but it does not provide options like connection timeout, disable keep-alive, idle connection timeout, etc. as provided by http transport.

I tried using ConfigureTransport function in http2 package but this doesn't work with h2c.

Code snippet which I used is:

```
protos := []string{"h2", "http/1.1"}
transport1 := &http.Transport{
    DisableCompression: !enableCompression,
    DisableKeepAlives:  !enableKeepAlive,
    DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout: dialTimeout,
    }).DialContext,
    IdleConnTimeout:     idleConnectionTimeout,
    MaxIdleConnsPerHost: idleConnectionsPerHost,
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        NextProtos: protos,
    },
}

if err := http2.ConfigureTransport(transport1); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

client := http.Client{
    Transport: transport1,
}

resp, err := client.Get("http://<server>/hello.html")
```

I was expecting communication over h2c to work with all the parameters specified. Am I missing something?